# Why is this throwing "read access violation"?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, c++-cx

Now I'm trying to show a progressbar dialog while reading and processing a file, but my code throws "read access violation" on closing the dialog.

Exact error message is,

```
**__pUnknown** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

And below is my code.

```cpp
void LoadFile(StorageFile^ file) {
    ContentDialog^ loaderDialog = ref new ContentDialog();
    loaderDialog->Title = L"Loading...";
    loaderDialog->Content = ref new ProgressBar();
    loaderDialog->ShowAsync();

    Concurrency::create_task(FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file))
        .then([&](Platform::String^ fileText) {

            // File processing parts are omitted.
            // ...

            loaderDialog->Hide(); // Read access violation!
        }
    );
}
```

Why this becomes an error?

Comment: Not an expert in C++/CX, but I'd try to capture by value [=] instead of by reference [&].

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts I think you are an expert! Thanks, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/ccx-part-2-of-n-types-that-wear-hats/

> So, what exactly is a ^ type? A hat type is a **smart pointer** type that
>   (1) automatically manages the lifetime of a Windows Runtime object and
>   (2) provides automatic type conversion capabilities to simplify use of
>   Windows Runtime objects.

You are taking a ref to the smart pointer, hence you are not increasing its reference count, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/rules-for-managing-reference-counts .
This means that when the continuation is executed the reference is dangling.

You can try capturing by value `[=]` instead of reference `[&]`.
Please note that you should consider, in the capture, capturing each variable instead of using `[=]` or `[&]`